# Group Pandas Dataframe by Year and Month

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe dft with two columns 'DATE' and 'Income'

```
dft = pd.DataFrame(chunk, columns=['DATE','Income'])
dft['DATE'] =  pd.to_datetime(dft['DATE'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
_= dft.sort_values(by='DATE', ascending=1)
```

I am now trying to sum the data up for each month of each year. This would mean the new dataframe has two columns like Jan 2012 and then the income for that month in that year. I can do this for just a month by using the following code but this doesn't take into account the year that month sits in. Is there a way I can groupby month and year?

```
monthlyincome = dft.groupby(dft['DATE'].dt.strftime('%B')) 
[['Income']].sum().reset_index()
```

The end goal is to then put this into a bar chart. I was thinking converting into two lists and then using something like:

```
plt.bar(xaxis,yaxis)
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Please make you example complete und verifiable. I can't instantiate your dataframe because `chunk` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
periods = dft.DATE.dt.to_period("M")
group = dft.groupby(periods).sum()
```

This should return you year and month combined.

Comment: Thanks, I did try this but I got the error " 'RangeIndex object has no attribute year"

Comment: Thanks for the update. Unfortunately I still get an error 'Grouper and axis must be the same length'

Comment: Thanks. I need the invoice dates not as an index however so I can plot them as columns.

Answer (score 0):

Final Solution was:

```
dft = pd.DataFrame(chunk, columns=['DATE','Income'])
dft['DATE'] =  pd.to_datetime(dft['DATE'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
_= dft.sort_values(by='DATE', ascending=1)

periods = dft.DATE.dt.to_period("M")
group = dft.groupby(periods).sum()
group = group.reset_index()
```

Thanks to Mayank.